# How to substitute sequential spaces individually in perl

Tags: perl, substitution

I want to replace every space in "a   b" with "\ " and the expected output is "a\ \ \ b". 
I have tried the following code but the output did not satisfy.

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
my $q = CGI -> new;
print $q -> header();
$input = "a   b";
(my $output = $input) =~ s/\ /\\ /;
```

the output is "a\   b" but not "a\ \ \ b".
How can I get it right?

Comment: Use the g flag as in `s/\/\\ /g;`

Comment: `tr` is suited to this task. `tr/ /\\/` Also the space need not be escaped, however the backslash in the replacement/transliteration will.

Comment: Why do people give answers as comments?  not OP doesn;t have an answer to select and I have to keep seeing it in my Unanswered questions search.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm

```
$input = "a   b";

$input =~ s/\s/\\/g;
```

Tested and works, my test code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$abc = "a          b";

 $abc =~ s/\s/\\/g;

print $abc, "\n";

Cerberus:~ alexmac$ ./testaaa.pl
a\\\\\\\\\\b
```

This should work nicely for you.  The idea is we are matching the \s and it will do it over and over until your matching any \s type character, the white space character set [regular expressions](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html)

Answer (score 1):

First up, as a previous answerer has already mentioned, you're just missing the /g ("global") modifier on your substitution regular expression.

```
alex@yuzu:~$ perl -E '$str = "a   b"; $str =~ s/ /\\ /g; say $str;'
a\ \ \ b
```

However going one step further, I wonder if you are looking to escape characters other than spaces. In that case you might want to look into using the `quotemeta()` builtin.

```
alex@yuzu:~$ perl -E '$str = q{a   b   ()+?$@%}; say quotemeta $str;'
a\ \ \ b\ \ \ \(\)\+\?\$\@\%
```

For more information see [`perldoc quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

Comment: I think your answer is best but your examples are hard to read. I would drop the prompt stuff and just use code with comments for output. That way they'll highlight right